# Analysis Arithmetic series .Verify which of the following sequences converge.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Verify which of the following sequences converge.$$1.A(n)=\sum_{n=1,n=+00}(1/(n^{1+1/n})$$  $$2. B(n)=(1/\sqrt{n^2+1})+.......n/\sqrt{n^2+n}$$

$$3.C(n)=(n+cos(n^2))/(n+sin(n)) $$ .For the 3th one cant i just take the absolute value  so $C(n)<=n+1/n-1$ ?? .For the first one i cant find a sequence to compare.And for the second one i say $B(n)<=n^2/\sqrt{n^2+n}<=n/\sqrt{1+1/n}$ but is not helping.

Comment: What is the source of the exercises?Is it homework?

Comment: @user159870 they where on a previus semester exam as 1 of the 5 exercises to pass the course of analysis.

Comment: The definition of $A(n)$ doesn't make sense.  The right-hand side doesn't depend on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Manoli, note that $n^{1/n} \lt 2$ for all $n$.

It follows that $\dfrac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}\gt \dfrac{1}{2n}$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n} \text{diverges}$$

so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$ also diverges.

Comment: sorry made a mistake of the function inside the sum.fixed it.

Comment: Look at my edited answer.Do you need further explanation?

Comment: compare it with $$1/1^{1+1/n}$$

Comment: ?? i cant find a function proper to compare it

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis I corrected my answer.

Comment: thanks i would choose you answer as accepted but i want help also with the other 2.

Comment: The first inequality is wrong.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n \sqrt[n]{n}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n} \sqrt[n]{n}}$$  is wrong

Comment: I will think about it.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Look at my edited answer.

Comment: @user159870  i compare it with 1/n  took the division and the limiti goes to 1 so because 1/n diverges so my other one.

Comment: @user159870 can you help me with the $B(n)$??